# Spring - Commit on transaction not inserting records but does not throw exceptions

Tags: java, database, spring, transactions, mybatis

In Spring + MyBatis I am performing some changes on my Postgres database within a transaction using the following code:

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition definition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
TransactionStatus status = dataSourceTransactionManager.getTransaction(definition);
try {
    // do insert, updates, deletes etc. on the DB
    dataSourceTransactionManager.commit(status);
    return stuffWithPksOfInsertedRecords;
} catch (Exception e) {
    dataSourceTransactionManager.rollback(status);
    return originalStuff;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes my code returns *stuffWithPksOfInsertedRecords* (i.e. passes over the commit without throwing exceptions), but actually the records inserted in transaction are not written to the Database after the commit, i.e. I now have pks of objects that are not actually stored in the database.

Is there any possible explanation for this behavior? Am I doing something wrong?

Note that the transaction may take some time to be fully performed, even a few minutes, may this be the problem? Can the default transaction expire?

Thank you

Comment: Where do you begin transaction? Which version of spring do you use? My spring 4 DataSourceTransactionManager does not have getTransaction methos

Comment: Spring 3.2.0 release. According to some tutorials I found there is no begin transaction using the aforementioned pattern